# Data from Drones class not loading into HTML but nearly identical class works

Tags: javascript

This is quite an elaborate tutorial app. Its from the Pluralsight ES6 javascript course. I want to finish it by displaying the drone table as well as the cars table. Presently everything else works.

Here is the full application: https://github.com/gareththomasnz/PluralsightJSOOP

There is a drones class & a cars class both of which get data from the fleet-data.js file.

In the course he stops short of loading the drones data which I decided to do. But it is not displaying.

I suspect the problem may be inside `fleet-data-service.js`:

```
import {Car} from '../classes/car.js';
import {Drone} from '../classes/drone.js';
import {DataError} from './data-error.js';

export class FleetDataService {

constructor() {
    this.cars = [];
    this.drones = []; 
    this.errors = [];       
}    

getCarByLicense(license) {
    return this.cars.find(function(car) {
        return car.license === license;
    });
}

getCarsSortedByLicense() {
    return this.cars.sort(function(car1, car2) {
        if (car1.license < car2.license)
            return -1;
        if (car1.license > car2.license)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}

filterCarsByMake(filter) {
    return this.cars.filter(car => car.make.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
}

getDroneByLicense(license) {
    return this.drones.find(function(drone) {
        return drone.license === license;
    });
}

getDronesSortedByLicense() {
    return this.drones.sort(function(drone1, drone2) {
        if (drone1.license < drone2.license)
            return -1;
        if (drone1.license > drone2.license)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}

filterDronesByBase(filter) {
    return this.drones.filter(drone => drone.base.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
} 

loadData(fleet) {
    for (let data of fleet) {
        switch(data.type) {
            case 'car':
                if (this.validateCarData(data)) {
                    let car = this.loadCar(data);
                    if (car) 
                        this.cars.push(car);
                }
                else {
                    let e = new DataError('invalid car data', data);
                    this.errors.push(e);
                }
                break;
            case 'drone':
                if (this.validateDroneData(data)) {
                    let drone = this.loadDrone(data);
                    if (drone) 
                        this.drones.push(drone);
                }
                else {
                    let e = new DataError('invalid drone data', data);
                    this.errors.push(e);
                }
                break;
            default:
                let e = new DataError('Invalid vehicle type', data);
                this.errors.push(e);
                break;
        }
    }
}

loadCar(car) {
    try {
        let c = new Car(car.license, car.model, car.latLong);
        c.miles = car.miles;
        c.make = car.make;
        return c;
    } catch(e) {
        this.errors.push(new DataError('error loading car', car));
    }
    return null;
}

validateCarData(car) {
    let requiredProps = 'license model latLong miles make'.split(' ');
    let hasErrors = false;

    for (let field of requiredProps) {
        if (!car[field]) {
            this.errors.push(new DataError(`invalid field ${field}`, car));
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    }

    if (Number.isNaN(Number.parseFloat(car.miles))) {
        this.errors.push(new DataError('invalid milage', car));
        hasErrors = true;
    }
    return !hasErrors;
}

loadDrone(drone) {
    try {
        let d = new Drone(drone.license, drone.model, drone.latLong);
        d.airTimeHours = drone.airTimeHours;
        d.base = drone.base;
        return d;
    } catch(e) {
        this.errors.push(new DataError('error loading drone', drone));
    }
    return null;
}
validateDroneData(drone) {
    let requiredProps = 'License Model airTimeHours Base'.split(' ');
    let hasErrors = false;

    for (let field of requiredProps) {
        if (!drone[field]) {
            this.errors.push(new DataError(`invalid field ${field}`, drone));
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    }

    if (Number.isNaN(Number.parseFloat(drone.airTimeHours))) {
        this.errors.push(new DataError('invalid Air hours', drone));
        hasErrors = true;
    }
    return !hasErrors;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the data is not shown results here:
`fleet-data-service.js`

in this method: `validateDroneData()` because of the return value false, because there are "errors".

```
let requiredProps = 'License Model airTimeHours Base'.split(' ');
```

You need to write the properties in lower case, like this:

```
let requiredProps = 'license model airTimeHours base'.split(' ');
```

After this one, the data is shown.
Then you have a new problem:

In `data-table.js` the check for the data properties is this line:

```
let field = row[property.toLowerCase()];
```

You hadn't any problems because the shown properties of the classes did fit.
Now with the `airTimeHours` in the class, the result is `undefined` because he checks now `airtimehours` (remember the .toLowerCase() above).

So just write as property `airtimehours` in your class.

`fleet-data-service.js`

```
d.airTimeHours = drone.airTimeHours;
```

in

```
d.airtimehours = drone.airTimeHours;
```

I hope this will get you further.